# How to update a specific submodule in my working directory to what's on GitLab remote repository

Tags: git, gitlab, git-submodules

I currently have the submodule `mysamplefolder` in my Gitlab remote repository:

[image]

The contents are below:

[image]

But that particular submodule in my local working directory doesn't have that file

[image]

**How can I update that `mysamplefolder` submodule in my local working directory so it's updated and in sync to what's currently on Gitlab?**

I'm not sure what are the steps to do this.
Should run:

```
git pull
```

But this will update the whole repository instead of that particular submodule? I'm also searching that this is an option (?)

```
git submodule update --recursive
```

I'm not sure what would you guys do in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A submodule is a nested repository: you can go in that local cloned folder (inside your parent repository), and, inside `mysamplefolder`, list the branches, switch to one and pull

```bash
cd /path/to/mysamplefolder
git branch -avv
# for instance
git switch main
git pull
```

Check if that is enough to show your file, and go back to your parent repository to record the new submodule state:

```bash
cd ..
git add mysamplefolder
git commit -m "mysamplefolder: new content"
git push
```